# Where must be WriteConcern implemented?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This is a code segment where I will insert PLC data into MongoDB but I am not sure as to where must WriteConcern be implemented?

```
    var connectionString = "mongodb://10.52.124.186:27017/";

    // Establish connection from the client to the server 
    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

    var server = client.GetServer();

    // Connect to the MongoDB specified for the GDS on the Mongodb
    var mongoDB = server.GetDatabase("test_database");

    // create a collection called sample
    var collection = mongoDB.GetCollection<sample>("sample");

    sample a = new sample();

    // Access the socket via which PLC has sent the data
    a.Parameter = data;

    collection.Insert(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several levels on which you can state your desired default WriteConcern level.

- On the Settings of the MongoClient object

  - either by passing a MongoSettings object to the constructor
  - or by setting `mongoClient.Settings.WriteConcern` later
- On database level by setting `database.Settings.WriteConcern`
- On collection level by setting `collection.Settings.WriteConcern`
- On every single database query by using the method overloads which take a `WriteConcern` object.

Each of these settings can of course be overridden by a different setting on a lower level. So which level you choose does depend on what you want to do.

Comment: Hi @Philipp,

If I want WriteConcern at the collection level, will it be like:

`collection.Insert(a, new MongoInsertOptions
   
{
                    
WriteConcern = WriteConcern.WMajority
                
}
                    );`

this?

Comment: @Arjun Or just do `collection.Insert(a, WriteConcern.WMajority)` But this is just for this one query, not for future queries on the same collection.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. So, what I want to do is to have a WriteConcern at the collection level, whenever the data is inserted into the collection, an acknowledegment will be sent by the MongoDB. How can the statement you mentioned above be changed to such a way?

Comment: @Arjun `collection.Settings.WriteConcern = WriteConcern.WMajority`

Comment: `collection.Insert(a);
 collection.Settings.WriteConcern = WriteConcern.WMajority;`

returns a 'MongoCollectionSettings is frozen' exception. Do I have to kill it or is the Insert statement not right?

Comment: @Arjun You can not change the write concern *after* sending a request. The MongoDB API is not capable of time-travel.

Comment: my bad, that was a ridiculous error on my part. Thanks for pointing out. I have to create a new MongoSettings class and then initialize a new instance of this class with the Settings right? And all these to be there before the code segment I posted in the topic question?